# Error in installing ultralytics in my raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, error-handling, raspberry-pi, ultralytics

Ive tred instaling ultralyics in my raspberry pi and its gettinng error in installng the pytorch and torchvision i suppose.
The error goes on like:
8

```
.0.85, ultralytics==8.0.86, ultralytics==8.0.87, ultralytics==8.0.88, ultralytics==8.0.89, ultralytics==8.0.9, ultralytics==8.0.90, ultralytics==8.0.91, ultralytics==8.0.92, ultralytics==8.0.93, ultralytics==8.0.94, ultralytics==8.0.95, ultralytics==8.0.96, ultralytics==8.0.97, ultralytics==8.0.98, ultralytics==8.0.99, ultralytics==8.1.0, ultralytics==8.1.1, ultralytics==8.1.10, ultralytics==8.1.11, ultralytics==8.1.12, ultralytics==8.1.13, ultralytics==8.1.14, ultralytics==8.1.15, ultralytics==8.1.16, ultralytics==8.1.17, ultralytics==8.1.18, ultralytics==8.1.19, ultralytics==8.1.2, ultralytics==8.1.20, ultralytics==8.1.22, ultralytics==8.1.23, ultralytics==8.1.24, ultralytics==8.1.25, ultralytics==8.1.26, ultralytics==8.1.27, ultralytics==8.1.3, ultralytics==8.1.4, ultralytics==8.1.5, ultralytics==8.1.6, ultralytics==8.1.7, ultralytics==8.1.8 and ultralytics==8.1.9 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    ultralytics 8.1.27 depends on torchvision>=0.9.0
    ultralytics 8.1.26 depends on torchvision>=0.9.0
   
......
```

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

whenever i try to install torch error arises....
pip install torch==1.12.0
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.12.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.12.0
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

Comment: Did you update pip version?

Answer (score 0):

Check your raspberry pi os bit version. PyTorch cannot be installed on a 32-bit Raspberry Pi OS. If your OS is 32-bit, consider upgrading to a 64-bit OS for compatibility with PyTorch.

To check OS version
`uname -m`
If it returns "armv7l", it's a 32-bit OS. If it returns "aarch64" or "arm64", it's a 64-bit